# Replying back the greetings from a muslim

Tags: halal-haram

I am a non-Muslim . If my muslims friends greets "Assalamualaikum" , would it be haram if i reply with "Waalaikumsalam" ?

Comment: halal or haram is a boundary of permissibility and it does not apply to non-Muslims. so you may reply like that, but it will be counted against neither halal nor haram

Comment: I'd rather you ask that question in the domain of the religion you are affiliated to, provide you are. Otherwise it really shouldn't matter to you.

Comment: Let me assume the op is trying to understand it more in case if it is not appropriate to do so. But as MAKZ, halal and haram is just for Muslims. Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you should believe in Islam but you don't find enough courage in yourself to confess in Islam, and want to behave like a Muslim instead, not to commit anything wrong at least, things would be different than when you are merely interested in Islam and like to interact with your friends in their own manner like you do the with your friends of other nations/religions.

If your case is the former, understanding the truth and denying it, or having reluctance to embrace because of fear of its side effects on your current life style and communications with family and friends, or just simply postponing the issue of making decision about it to tomorrow (a tomorrow that may never turn into Today), that would be considered as wrong (like Haram that you said) even from non-Muslims.

If your case is the latter, that would be nice of you to respect their way of living and it will not be Haram or even wrong. That shows you are not an arrogant person and Allah likes it for you and all of us. In a Hadeeth from the Holy Prophet peace be upon him and his household we are told that after believing in Allah nothing is more be liked to Allah than us being tolerating and affable with respect to the people He has created, not even only with respect to the other believers but to all.

Comment: If by "brevity" you meant braveness/courage then I don't see how "denying" and "postponing" follows (second paragraph). If not then I don't see how brevity fits into first sentence.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, making a big decision is not always as easy as giving lecture about it might be, it needs brevity and a strong will, the person must not scare of how bad his/her friends and family will react to such a decision, and etc. . At this point some people know they should change their opinion but are afraid of its side effects, so either choose to deny what they've identified as truth and try to instead justify the way they used to belong to. Some others do not deny the truth but postpone making decision about it to a later time.

Comment: [Brevity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brevity) means something totally different. Denying it and postponing it for lack of importance is not the same as reluctance to embrace because of fear.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, Oh I see! Brevity is totally different, all due to my English being lame, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Doesn't matter we are all here to learn or share a little of what we know. Please address the second sentence in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact your friend might even be pleased that you made an effort to learn more about his/her faith. Comment by MAKZ stands true also.

In case you are curious, `AsSalamu Alaikum` means `peace be with you` and the appropriate response to/for a muslim is `wa Alaikum Assalam` ie `And onto you peace`. This is the greeting that prophets like Jesus ,peace be upon him, also used in his time.

Peace be with you!

Comment: How does this not answer the question, I answered no it would not be haram and then explained it.

Comment: My bad, the terseness eluded me. Apologies. But please refrain from a using `lol`s and other frivolous statements in the posts.

Comment: *Chortle* I knew you'd find something else bleeding fingers, ya sly old devil you. Aiight man I shall refrain from using frivolous stuff in future, after all, I am newbie at this and there is much room to improve (especially after that welcoming).
Salam alikum, peace be with you.

Comment: @Jam newbies tend to get downvoted! it happened with me too. That was because I didnot provide reference and provided an answer from my own logic, although correct. So from next attempt onwards, provide references to your answer

Answer (score 1):

"Assalamualaikum" means "Peace be upon you" and "Waalaikumsalam" is a reply "Peace be upon you, too". These are normal arabic words. If you like it, you can say it.

This is very old tradition of different prophets. Quran mentions about the [greeting by Prophet Abraham (PBUH).](http://quran.com/11/69)

> And certainly did Our messengers come to Abraham with good tidings; they said, "Peace." He said, "Peace," and did not delay in bringing [them] a roasted calf.

All the major religions have similar words for greetings. Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) sanctioned this tradition and now it is global greeting message among the muslims all over the world.